# string comparison with output in Bash

Tags: bash, string-comparison

I have a simple script that works great (and prints `hello`)

```
variable=false
if [ "$variable" = "false" ]; then
    echo hello
fi
```

However, this does not work (and does not print `hello`)

```
variable=$(source script.sh \
           | awk -F":" '/maintenanceMode\>/ { print $2i }' \
           | sed 's/,//g'
          )
echo $variable     # prints `false`, as expected
if [ "$variable" = "false" ]; then
    echo hello
fi
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure that the value of `variable` in the second example is `false`? Can you echo it before your test?

Comment: @BenjaminW.   Yes absolutely, triple checked

Comment: What's in `script.sh`? Is there a reason why you source it instead of just executing it?

Comment: And with "triple checking", did you do `echo "$variable"` after the assignment, and no just check the output of the command you substitute?

Comment: script.sh contains curl command that connects to cloudera manager and checks in the cluster is in the maintenance mode. curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://$USERNAME:$PASSWORD@$HOST:$PORT/api/$API_VERSION/clusters 2>&1 .  Yes i did echo $variable and it returned false

Comment: What if you do `echo "'$variable'"` - there might be whitespace.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, do you know how to do something like "$variable" = *false

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171189/discussion-between-benjamin-w-and-user3508766).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strip whitespaces from your variable.

```
$variable=`echo $variable | xargs`
```

Comment: Thank you, I have added " | xargs" and it solved my problem since i had a whitespace